# A memory-efficient large array of words

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for a Java data structure for storing a large text (about a million words), such that I can get a word by index (for example, get the 531467 word).

The problem with String[] or ArrayList is that they take too much memory - about 40 bytes per word on my environment.

I thought of using a String[] where each element is a chunk of 10 words, joined by a space. This is much more memory-efficient - about 20 bytes per word; but the access is much slower.

Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: 40 bytes per word and a million words is 40MB, which is a tiny amount of memory these days. Do you *really* need it to be less than this? Is it for a mobile application for example?

Comment: do you meen 40 bytes *overhead* per word?

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but why do you have the requirement to look up a word by its index?

Comment: why not just store everything in a single string, and have an int[] with the start positions of all words?

Comment: @Thilo Wouldn't an additional int[] for the end positions of all words also be useful?

Comment: @Jon, I am on Google App Engine. They give me only about 120 MB, and I have other data structures, so every MB is important.

Comment: @Axel, because it's part of a word suffix array in a random text generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings
```

> Use a byte[] for Strings which can be represented as pure ASCII.
>   (Introduced in Java 6 Update 21 Performance Release)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Seems like a interesting article:
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_saving_memory.shtml

I hear ropes are quite good in terms of speed in storing large strings, though not sure memory wise. But you might want to check it out.
http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29

Comment: The link from javamex helped me a lot. I ended up using intern(), as mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

As Jon Skeet already mentioned, 40mb isn't too large.

But you stated that you are storing a text, so there may be many same Strings. 
For example stop words like "and" and "or".

You can use String.intern()[1]. This will pool your String and returns a reference to an already existing String.

intern() quite slow, so you can replace this by a HashMap that will do the same trick for you.

[1] http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29

Comment: Interning isn't really appropriate here, since it uses up permgen. Better go with a `HashMap`.

Comment: I tried intern() and it lowered my memory consumption to only 10 bytes per string, with almost no performance time penalty.

@gustafc, can you please elaborate, why is this a problem?

Comment: What HashMap exactly? I tried this:

 private Map<String,Integer> words = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); // store the first index of the word 

 @Override public void add(String word) {
  if (words.containsKey(word))
   myList.add(myList.get(words.get(word)));
  else {
   words.put(word, myList.size());
   myList.add(word);
  }
 }
memory usage is about 24 bytes per string, which is good, but not nearly as intern. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Erel Segal: The memory for interned strings is allocated from the "permanent generation", which is fairly small and houses other things like class data. You don't want to use more of permgen than you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using [memory mapping the data structure](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm), but performance might be completely horrible.

Answer (score 2):

Store all the words in a single string:

```
class WordList {

    private final String content;
    private final int[] indices;

    public WordList(Collection<String> words) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        indices = new int[words.size()];
        int currentWordIndex = 0;
        int previousPosition = 0;
        for (String word : words) {
            buf.append(word);
            indices[currentWordIndex++] = previousPosition;
            previousPosition += word.length();
        }
        content = buf.toString();
    }

    public String wordAt(int index) {
        if (index == indices.length - 1) return content.substring(indices[index]);
        return content.substring(indices[index], indices[index + 1]);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        WordList list = new WordList(Arrays.asList(args));
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("Word %d: %s%n", i, list.wordAt(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Apart from the characters they contain, each word has an overhead of four bytes using this solution (the entry in `indices`). Retrieving a word with `wordAt` will always allocate a new string; you could avoid this by saving the `toString()` of the `StringBuilder` rather than the builder itself, although it uses more memory on construction.

Depending on the kind of text, language, and more, you might want a solution that deals with recurring words better (like [the one previously proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039384/a-memory-efficient-large-array-of-words/7039643#7039643)).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to store byte arrays instead with the text encoded in UTF-8:

```
byte[][] words = ...;
```

Then:

```
public String getWord(int index)
{
   return new String(words[index], "UTF-8");
}
```

This will be smaller in two ways:

- The data for each string is *directly* in a byte[], rather than the String having a couple of integer members and a reference to a separate char[] object
- If your text is mostly-ASCII, you'll benefit from UTF-8 using a single byte per character for those ASCII characters

I wouldn't really recommend this approach though... again it will be slower on access, as it needs to create a new `String` each time. Fundamentally, if you need a million string objects (so you don't want to pay the recreation penalty each time) then you're going to have to use the memory for a million string objects...

Comment: That looks like a good idea, I will try this. 

The file has a million strings, but I don't need all of them in the same run - it's a random text generator that peeks sentences at random.

Comment: OK, I tried both byte[] and char[] (since my data is mostly non-ASCII), and it saved me 33% of memory consumption - good but not enough.

Comment: @Erel: It would have been useful if you'd told us before that most of the data is non-ASCII. Anything else you can think of that could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a datastructure like this:

- `List<string> wordlist`
- `Dictionary<string, int> tsildrow // for reverse lookup while building the structure`
- `List<int> wordindex`

`wordlist` will contain a list of all (unique) words,
`tsildrow` will give the index of a word in `wordlist` and `wordindex` will tell you the index in `wordlist` of a specific index in your text.

You would operate it in the following fashion:

```
for word in text:
    if not word in tsildrow:
        wordlist.append(word)
        tsildrow.add(word, wordlist.last_index)
    wordindex.append(tsildrow[word])
```

this fills up your datastructure. Now, to find the word at index 531467:

```
print wordlist[wordindex[531467]]
```

you can reproduce the entire text like this:

```
for index in wordindex:
    print wordlist[index] + ' '
```

except, that you will still have a problem of punctuation etc...

if you won't be adding any more words (i.e. your text is stable), you can delete `tsildrow` to free up some memory if this is a concern of yours.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have experimented with several of your suggestions, and here are my results (I checked (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) before filling the array, and checked again after filling the array and gc()):

- Original (array of strings): 54 bytes/word (not 40 as I mistakenly wrote)
- My solution (array of chunks of strings, separated by spaces):
- - 2 words per chunk - 36 b/w (but unacceptable performance)
- - 10 words per chunk - 18 b/w
- - 100 words per chunk - 14 b/w
- byte arrays - 40 b/w
- char arrays - 36 b/w
- HashMap, either mapping a string to itself, or mapping a string to its index - 26 b/w
- - (not sure I implemented this correctly)
- intern - 10 b/w
- baseline (empty array) - 4 b/w

The average word length is about 3 chars, and most chars are non-ASCII so it's probably about 6 bytes. So, it seems that intern is close to the optimum. It makes sense, since it's an array of words, and many of the words appear much more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably consider using a file, with either fixed sized words or some sort of index. FileInputStream with skip can be pretty efficient

Comment: I doubt that going to the file system will be faster than the already-rejected "ten words at a time" approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mobile device you can use TIntArrayList which would use 4 bytes per int value. If you use one index per word it will one need a couple of MB. You can also use `int[]`

If you have a PC or server, this is trivial amount of memory. Memory cost about £6 per GB or 1 cent per MB.